# Passing data to multiple forms in flask-wtforms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Consider this :

```
{% for user in users.query.all() %}
     <tr>
         <form method='POST' action="">
             <td>{{form.username}}</td>
             <td>{{form.description}}</td>
             <td>{{form.submit(value="Update")}}</td>
         </form>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

For each user this will create a small form that I can update, I want to populate these forms with current database data

What I tried to do in the routes file:

```
@app.route("/Users")
def listUsers():
    users = Users
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        for user in users.query.all():
            form.username.data = user.username
            form.description.data = user.description
    return render_template('Users.html', users=users, form=form)
```

This results in having the data of the last user populating all of the forms, how can I go about fixing this ?
I was thinking of assigning an id to each form that matchs the user, but how would I be able to send a dynamic number of forms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while, but I got a work around, just gonna post it if anyone else has the same issue:

I used javascript ... created a function and called it within the for loop which populated the fields for me

```
function populateForm(username,description){
    var form = document.getElementById('form id here');
    form.nextElementSibling.value = username;
    form.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent = description;
}
```

note that I used value for input field and textContent for textfield, then inside the for loop i added a script tag

```
<script>
    populateForm('{{user.username}}','{{user,description}}');
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. Its better to see code for people who run to the same problem.